# Instance variable with the same value for different objects although different values were assigned

Tags: java, setter

First of all and before posting my question let me ask you people to stop downvoting my questions even if they seem stupid to you ,this site is an important place for me, it helps me a lot with my java doubts which are many,a question ban would be an heavy setback for me, so be helpful even by not answering!
Now for the question,

I have this method were i assign a value to a setter method with user input

```
public void addName() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to add a citizen name?");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        while (!answer.equals("y") || (!answer.equals("n"))) {

            if (answer.equals("y")) {
                String giveName = input.nextLine();
                this.setName(giveName);
                break;
            } else if (answer.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Not adding a name!");
                break;
            }else{System.out.println("Please choose y or n!");
            answer = input.nextLine();}
        }


    }
```

this method is later called in main from object `p1` and object `p2` and being assigned a differend value for each one to the instance variable name

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class MainClass  {



        public static void main(String[] args) {


            ArrayList<Pessoas> lista = new ArrayList<Pessoas>();
            Pessoas p1 = new Portugueses();
            Pessoas p2 = new Alemaes();

    p1.addName();
    p2.addName();

        System.out.println(p1.getName());
        System.out.println(p2.getName());

        }
    }
```

but when i call the `getName()` method at the end of main both `p1` and `p2` have the same value!
Shouldn't each object get it´s own copy of an instance variable?

Comment: Perhaps you declared your name variable as static.

Comment: You didn't post the relevant code. `Pessoas` class.

Comment: what is your getName look like?

Comment: setName() is also relevant

Comment: Yes ,your right i was experimenting yesterday with static methods and variables and forgot to erase static expression before the declaration of name !Thanks man

Comment: Thank you people for the help but is alredy solved !

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in your `addName()`-function. Your running your loop(`while (!answer.equals("y") || (!answer.equals("n")))`) until a `y` or `n` is entered. So as soon as you enter it, your loop will stop.

In your loop your checking if the input that was made cotains a `y` or `n`. Now the problem should be clear. Your loop won't run with those two values entered, but inside the loop you want to check if one of those is entered.

Two little personal hints(everyone has another style): Don't use `break;` let your loops end themselfs. Do it with an boolean-variable and updating it's state.

The second hint would be to use one `Scanner`-Object. For example you could add a `Scanner`-parameter to your `addName`-function. Just init one in your `MainClass`.

Those hints and fixes of the problem applied to your code could look like that:

```
    public void addName(Scanner input) {
       System.out.println("Do you want to add a citizen name?");
       String answer;
       boolean isAnotherInputNeeded = true;

       while (isAnotherInputNeeded) {

           answer = input.nextLine();

           if (answer.equals("y")) 
           {
               System.out.println("What's the name?");
               String giveName = input.nextLine();
               this.setName(giveName);
               isAnotherInputNeeded= false;
           } 
           else if (answer.equals("n")) 
           {
               System.out.println("Not adding a name!");
               this.setName("No name entered");
               isAnotherInputNeeded= false;;
           }
           else
           {
               System.out.println("Please choose y or n!");
           }
           input.reset();
       }
    }
```

And your `MainClass`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<Pessoas> lista = new ArrayList<Pessoas>();

      Pessoas p1 = new Pessoas();
      Pessoas p2 = new Pessoas();

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      p1.addName(input);
      p2.addName(input);

      System.out.println("You entered the following names:");
      System.out.println(p1.getName());
      System.out.println(p2.getName());

  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The point of my while loop is to repeat the mesage "please choose y or n" untill y or n is entered ,at this point the code corresponding to the answer entered will run and then break out of the loop.It works perfectly well here,,honestly i don´t undestand why you say that the problem is clear?